# It is divided into 3 parts by randomly taking two different points on a line segment.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is divided into 3 parts by randomly taking two different points on a line segment.

1. What is the probability that all three are of equal length?
2. What is the probability that the leftmost is smallest?

My thoughts: I thought the answer to the first question should be 0. Because the desired number of points is 2, but the number of points that can be selected is infinite.

The answer to the second question should be 1/3. Because the shortest piece is either on the left, in the middle, or on the right. There is no other situation.

What do you think?İs it true? Thanks.

Comment: I believe answers to both questions are correct, but I believe solution for second question is not correct. How do you know that all three described situations are equiprobable?